# Display in dialog box the thumbnail of image uri from gallery

Tags: android

I'm picking images in gallery and listing it in the listview. What I want to do is when I click the image uri item in the listview, the thumbnail of it will appear. But whenever I click the item, nothing is displayed in dialog box. Just plain white.

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<Uri> array_list = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    ArrayAdapter<Uri> array_adapter;

    final int RQS_LOADIMAGE = 0;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false); 

        ImageButton b = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.button_ai);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);

        array_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Uri>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_style, array_list);
        lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_ai);
        lv.setAdapter(array_adapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 

                AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());  

                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(array_list.get(position).toString()); 

                ImageView thumbView = new ImageView(getActivity());
                thumbView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
                layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                layout.addView(thumbView);

                adb.setView(layout);
                adb.show(); 
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) 
        {           
            case R.id.button_ai:
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_LOADIMAGE);
            break;
        }           
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

      if (requestCode == RQS_LOADIMAGE) {

          if(resultCode == MainActivity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            array_list.add(imageUri);
            array_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          }
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: 2 questions: 1- did you check to see if this code works in an activity and not in a fragment? 2- did you check if you get the URI and if so, post it here.. you can try adding "file://" before the uri string

Comment: @matan dahan - 1- nope. 2 - yes. It displays in my listview as content://media/external/images/media/3971 what will I post? the screenshots? I can't post pictures here. I need more reputation. You mean String s2 = "file://" + bmp?

Comment: I would recommand to use Picasso image loader, it will solve you the memory problem mentioned by @corsair992 and also will solve you the problem of loading the image without "openInputStream()" method.. go [HERE](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for more information, and this is the simple method which should work for you: Picasso.with(getActivity())
  .load(array_list.get(position).toString())
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(thumbView)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use the `decodeFile()` method with a `Uri`; instead use the static `getBitmap()` helper method from the `MediaStore.Images.Media` class to load the `Bitmap`.

**Edit:**

Also if you want to display a thumbnail, you should scale it down for performance and better memory footprint. You can read about how to do that from [this guide](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html). You can provide the `BitmapFactory.Options` by opening an `InputSteam` from the `ContentResolver` with the `openInputStream()` method, and calling `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()`.

Also you should not load these `Bitmap`s from the main thread; this logic should be moved inside an `AsyncTask` or `Loader` implementation.

Comment: Like this? Uri imageUri = data.getData(); Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);

Comment: Why I'm getting an error saying "the method getContentResolver() is undefined for the type Fragment1"?

Comment: @user3012327: Sorry, you need to change that to  `getActivity().getContentResolver()`.

Comment: Thanks. It's working now. One more question, if I set it to "getActivity().getContentResolver()" I'm getting an error saying "Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException and IOException" the solution that eclipse is giving me, is surround it with try and catch. I did that and it's working. My question is, why I'm getting that error and need to surround it with try and catch?

Comment: @user3012327: You need the handle these exceptions, because they can be thrown by the `getBitmap()` method. `FileNotFoundException` will be thrown if the `Uri` doesn't point to a valid existing file path, and `IOException` will be thrown if there is an error occurs while closing the `InputStream` of the `File`. They should not occur in practice in your case, but since the `getBitmap()` method has declared that it can throw these exceptions, the compiler forces you to handle them.